# Cannot install "glog" for React Native app

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, glog

I am stuck trying to run `pod install` to get my new React-Native App to build. I've had a look online - my `xcode-select` command is set correctly which seems to be the main solutions to this problem. Here is my output, does anyone have any clues?

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.4.sdk
checking whether the C compiler works... no
/Users/lachlanedwards/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-1f3da/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/Users/lachlanedwards/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-1f3da/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: in `/Users/lachlanedwards/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-1f3da':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: I'm experiencing there same issue.  I've tried all solutions posted so far online but nothing is working

Comment: Same error, did you find any solution?